# How to add a property to sub-objects with a certain parameter/value in JS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object

I've got an object and i want to iterate through all of its subobjects/keys that hold the key-value pair 'pool: "luxury"'. Or in other words I want to iterate throu all rooms that are in the pool luxury to set a new parameter. What is a proper and efficient way to do that in js?

```
var rooms = {
    SU01: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su01.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU02: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su02.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU03: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su03.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU11: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su11.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU12: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su12.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    ...
```

Comment: What is the new property you want to set on the filtered set?

Comment: Its some more or less complex merging of time periods which will result in a new object that will be stored in each room.

named "merged_ics"

Comment: Do you want to create a new object, or update this one?

Comment: @torazaburo: update this one

Comment: @haemse - i've updated my solution to update the `rooms` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to get all the values in the object and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to only keep the ones you want.

The code might look like this:

```
foreach (let room of Object.values(rooms).filter(r => r.pool == 'luxury')) {
    // Do something with room
}
```

Comment: This only filters the objects matching the string. It does not add a new property to the objects as it asks in the question.

Comment: At this point yes. I didn't know about Object.values though. I've changed it now. Thanks again!

Comment: The current node.js version does not support Obejct.entries()

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your data set

```
const data = var rooms = {
    SU01: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su01.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU02: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su02.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU03: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su03.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU11: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su11.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU12: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su12.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
};
```

If the properties under the which the rooms are returned are important, we need to add those into the room objects, like this

```
const rooms = Object.keys(data).map(id => ({
  id,
  ...data[key],
}));
```

Otherwise, we can have all the rooms by simply calling

```
const rooms = Object.values(data);
```

Now that we have the rooms, we have to filter the get the ones with `pool` equals to `luxury`

```
const luxuryRooms = rooms.filter(room => room.pool === 'luxury');
```

Eventually you can add a new property with

```
const updatedRooms = luxuryRooms.map(room => ({
  ...room,
  newProperty: 'New Value',
}));
```

Comment: This only filters the objects matching the string. It does not add a new property to the objects as it asks in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With `lodash`:

```
var _ = require('lodash')

_(rooms)
    .values()
    .filter(r => r.pool == poolName)
    .value()
```

Output:

```
[ { enabled: true,
    pool: 'luxury',
    ics_lnk: 'https://avlblty.com/su02.ics',
    ics_txt: '' },
  { enabled: true,
    pool: 'luxury',
    ics_lnk: 'https://avlblty.com/su03.ics',
    ics_txt: '' },
  { enabled: true,
    pool: 'luxury',
    ics_lnk: 'https://avlblty.com/su12.ics',
    ics_txt: '' } ]
```

Comment: This only filters the objects matching the string. It does not add a new property to the objects as it asks in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that will work in most modern browsers. The result is a new object with a new property on the items from the input object matching your filter.

Instead of hardcoding the function to work with one filter I've made a function (`addPropToFiltered()`) that accepts parameters for the property/value you want to filter on, and parameters for adding a new value.

This mutates the original `rooms` object, but can also be easily changed to create a new object (and leave `rooms` as is).

The function works like this;

```
addPropToFiltered(inputObject, filterProp, filterValue, newProp, newPropValue);
```

For your particular question we would use this as:

```
addPropToFiltered(rooms, "pool", "luxury", "newProp", "New Value");
```

which would add a new property of `newProp` with a value of `New Value` to each room matching `pool: "luxury"`.

```js
const addPropToFiltered = function(rooms, prop, filter, newProp, newValue) {
  return Object.keys(rooms).reduce(function(result, id) {
    const room = rooms[id];

    // Add new property if applicable
    if (room[prop] === filter) {
      room[newProp] = newValue;
    }

    result[id] = room;
    return result;
  }, {})
}

const rooms = {
  SU01: {
    enabled: true,
    pool: "comfort",
    ics_lnk: "https://avlblty.com/su01.ics",
    ics_txt: "",
  },
  SU02: {
    enabled: true,
    pool: "luxury",
    ics_lnk: "https://avlblty.com/su02.ics",
    ics_txt: "",
  },
  SU03: {
    enabled: true,
    pool: "luxury",
    ics_lnk: "https://avlblty.com/su03.ics",
    ics_txt: "",
  },
  SU11: {
    enabled: true,
    pool: "comfort",
    ics_lnk: "https://avlblty.com/su11.ics",
    ics_txt: "",
  },
  SU12: {
    enabled: true,
    pool: "luxury",
    ics_lnk: "https://avlblty.com/su12.ics",
    ics_txt: "",
  }
};

console.log(addPropToFiltered(rooms, "pool", "luxury", "newProp", "New Value"));

console.log(rooms)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is ES2015 and clear in that it does not mutate any objects (`rooms` is completely untouched):

```js
const addProperties = (rooms, pool, properties) => Object
    .keys(rooms) // take the keys "SU01", "SU02",...
    .filter(key => rooms[key].pool === pool) // take only keys with matching pool
    .reduce((newRooms, key) => ({ ...newRooms,
             [key]: { ...rooms[key], ...properties } // add properties to room
         }), rooms); // take "rooms" and update all changed rooms, which results in "newRooms"

const rooms = {
    SU01: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su01.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU02: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su02.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU03: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su03.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU11: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "comfort",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su11.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    },
    SU12: {
        enabled: true,
        pool: "luxury",
        ics_lnk : "https://avlblty.com/su12.ics",
        ics_txt : "",
    }
};

const result = addProperties(rooms, "luxury", { newProperty: "new value" });

console.log(result);
```